# Installation of Fuse IDE 7.1 not working

Tags: java, eclipse, fuseesb

I have installed Fuse IDE 7.1.60 (http://repo.fusesource.com/ide/) as a plugin to Eclipse Kepler (clean installation).

My OS is Windows 7 (64bit) and I'm having Oracle Java 1.7 JDK installed into a path with no whitespaces and JAVA_HOME set. Eclipse recognizes the JDK.

Unfortunately, in the "File|New" menu there is no "Fuse Project" option and neither in the "Window|Preferences".

I would be very thankful for hints, which could cause this behaviour!

There are only a few messages in the eclipse log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-08-30 17:06:33.091
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.fusesource.ide.branding.preferences.root (bundle: org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor, page: org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor.preferences.FusePreferencePage)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-08-30 17:06:33.096
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.fusesource.ide.branding.preferences.root (bundle: org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor, page: org.fusesource.ide.camel.editor.preferences.FuseColorPreferencePage)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-08-30 17:06:33.097
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.fusesource.ide.branding.preferences.root (bundle: org.fusesource.ide.deployment, page: org.fusesource.ide.preferences.deployment.page)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-08-30 17:06:33.097
!MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: org.fusesource.ide.branding.preferences.root (bundle: org.fusesource.ide.jvmmonitor.ui, page: org.fusesource.ide.jvmmonitor.ui.JavaMonitorPreferencePage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuse IDE 7.1. does not work with Eclipse Kepler. It only works with Eclipse 3.x. The Fuse IDE 6.0 (From JBoss) works with Eclipse 4.0. And the upcoming JBoss Fuse IDE 6.1 is likely to work with latest Eclipse 4.x version when its released.

You can see the Fuse IDE 7.1 documentation here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/Fuse_IDE/

Comment: I've seen that the integration into kepler was resolved in v6.1 (https://fusesource.com/issues/browse/ECLIPSE-932). I was confused by the versioning!